# iOS Achievement: "Share on Facebook and Twitter"

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I want to create achievement in my iOS game, which player will reaches when he shares my game (link to app store) on Facebook and Twitter. Do you think it is ok. I'm little bit worried that this update of my game will be rejected by Apple.

Thank you

Comment: There's no reason for Apple to reject you because you added an achievement to your game - especially one like this. There are hundreds of games with achievements like that. Read up on the review guidelines. Also, this question is probably off-topic and should be deleted / closed.

Comment: I asked this question because I read about similar troubles with app voting. Thank you